# Limit Bandwidth per Connection using Cisco ASA 5510

Tags: cisco-asa

Cisco ASA 5510

I have a 15Mbps connection.  Is it possible to limit the amount of bandwidth used per user either by bit or percentage?

For example, any of these would satisfy my requirements:

(1) User A can only use 500KB/s of my bandwidth (Leaves 1000KB/s for everyone else)

(2) User A can only use 25% of my total bandwidth (Leaves 1125KB/s for everyone else)

Using policing, I've only been able to rate limit the total bandwidth used by everyone on the connection.  Thanks.

Comment: I seirously doubt there would be any way to do it by "user" unless you assigned each user a static IP address. From there, I'm thinking perhaps some bastardization of QoS to rate limit

Comment: so it seems like i need another appliance/application to handle that?

Comment: You could probably do it on the cheap with a proxy server like squid (and then in fact, do it by user). Most firewalls are not packetshapers and if they are they tend to use QoS to pull it off.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to do it by user, I'm perfectly fine doing it by IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of the ASA software (8.4) appears to integrate with Active Directory and allow rules based on users, so if you use Active Directory you might be able to do what you want, although I suspect it isn't all that easy.

Check out the [release notes for ASA 8.4](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/release/notes/asarn84.html#wp535067) for more info.

Comment: Hmm, definitely looks like an interesting/promising feature.  Thanks!